# How to convert .update package into Sitecore Package or SCWDP package?

Tags: packages, update-packages

We received a hotfix from **Sitecore Support**, but it was provided as a `.update package` to be installed via `control panel>administration>install` an update (same as Sitecore Updates system).

As we do **blue green deployments** on Azure, I **can't** use this type of package in my `continuous process`.

Is there any way to convert .update packages into a `traditional Sitecore Package` (for package installer) or SCWDP package?

Comment: Gabe's answer is 100% correct, but most of the time a hotfix provided by Sitecore support does only contains config, a support dll with not any item related changes in Sitecore. if you have that kind of .update package you can use it in SCWDP package.

Answer (score 1):

The .update package is just a compressed file. You can rename the file by replacing .update with .zip to view and extract any files that would be installed during the installation process

For items, your best bet is to install the .update package on a local instance of Sitecore and create a new Sitecore package using the Package Designer.

Comment: That's totally true and is what I did in this case, but I was more looking for a generic, automated way.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sat/26/sitecore-azure-toolkit/en/web-deploy-packages-for-a-module.html):

> You can use a Sitecore module ZIP package or a Team Development for Sitecore .update package and convert it into an equivalent .scwdp.zip package that is compatible with MSDeploy by using the following PowerShell call:
>
> `ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage [-Path] <string> [[-Destination] <string>]`

The command comes from Sitecore Azure Toolkit that can be downloaded [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Azure_Toolkit.aspx).

I can confirm that this works for `Sitecore zip packages` but never tried to convert `.update` packages.

Here is the example usage:

```
$workingDirectory       = $PSScriptRoot
$toolkitDirectory       = "$workingDirectory\sat"
$modulesOutputDirectory = "$workingDirectory\modules"
$scPackagePath          = "$workingDirectory\Redirect.Manager-0.5.zip"
$scWdpPackagePath       = "$modulesOutputDirectory\Redirect.Manager-0.5.scwdp.zip"

Import-Module "$toolkitDirectory\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1"
Import-Module "$toolkitDirectory\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll"

ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path $scPackagePath -Destination $modulesOutputDirectory
```

Generated scwdp package can be extended with additional files if needed:

```
Update-SCWebDeployPackage -SourcePath "$workingDirectory\add\redirects-manager" -Path $scWdpPackagePath
```

Or with custom parameters:

```
Update-SCWebDeployPackage -ParametersXmlPath "$workingDirectory\redirect.manager.parameters.xml" -Path $scWdpPackagePath
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Gabe Streza.  You can change the .update extension to .zip.  I prefer to create a Nuget package using Nuget Package Explorer, pushing to an Azure DevOps Artifact feed and referencing that package in a Project module.

There are step-by-step instructions here: https://sitecoresnacks.com/2021/02/01/packaging-part-1-package-managers/

Comment: You need to add the relevants parts of your post to the answer here so it is self contained, and not a link only answer.